# is there a way to determine which layout has been selected in a Google Meet

Tags: hangouts-api

In a Google Meet, you can click the vertical ellipsis and then change the layout.

I have written an extension for which the tiled layout gives the best results, but I can't seem to find (programmatically) which view is being used. Any tips or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no mention as of today of getting or setting Meet layout in its [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/meet); neither you can [list its activities](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list) or get them from [System Parameters](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/system-parameters). If you need this feature, I would suggest you to open an [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) case asking for it. Feel free to ask me more if needed.